# PHP use a variable from a different file

Tags: php, session, variables, echo

I have a login page which records the username that the user enters and adds it to a variable of $uname. However when the page after the login page loads, I cannot echo the $uname. For example, when i type

```
Welcome <?php echo $uname; ?>
```

it does not insert the username.

below is a copy of my login-validation code. but I am not sure if the $_SESSION variable is working correctly, or how to reference it in my profile.php file.

```
<?php
session_start();
  $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;

// Grab User submitted information
$uname = $_POST["uname"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("mysql.*********.co.uk","******","************");
// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

// Select the database to use
mysql_select_db("onedirectionaffection_members",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT uname, pass FROM users WHERE uname = $uname");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row["uname"]==$uname && $row["pass"]==$pass)
  header("Location: ../../profile/profile.php");
else
    echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";


?>
```

If anyone could help I would be hugely thankful. Also, I am an absolute beginner at all of this so if you need anymore details I'll try my best to answer.

profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['uname'];
  ?>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>1D Affection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" Type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" Type="text/css" href="../css/font.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" Type="text/css" href="../css/profile.css" />
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="white">

    <div id="wrapperhead">
      <div id="headcont">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="../images/1DA logo ripped.png" height="150px">
        </div>

        <div class="subheading">
          <img src="../images/1d subheading.png" height="150px">
        </div>
      </div>


      </div> <!--END OF HEADER-->
    <div id="nav">




      <div class="navigation">

        <ul>

          <li><a class="nav" href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Fan-fiction</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="http://www.onedirectionstore.com/" target="_blank">Store</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div> <!-- END OF MENU-->
         <!-- END OF NAVIGATION-->
    </div>

      <div id="wrappercontent">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="maincont">
            <div class="profcust">


          <div class="profpic">

            </div>

            <div class="profinfo">

            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="username">
         Welcome <?php session_start(); echo $uname; ?>
            </div>

        <div class="story">

            </div>



          </div>
      <div class="sidenav">
        Coming Soon

          </div>


        </div><!--end of content-->

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be inside all the files.

Comment: Shouldn't you be grabbing the user information before setting the `$_SESSION` variable for `$uname`.

Comment: For reference: Your SQL has a gaping security hole in it: sql-injection. Please take note that the code above should be used purely as demo-code and should never be used like this in production.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to protect it from an injection attack? thanks

Comment: You have 2x instances of `session_start();` inside `profile.php` you're creating a new session while overwriting your first. @RJcreatives

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you haven't added `session_start();` on top of your profile.php page.

Try like this

```
//profile.php
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['uname'];
```

Comment: I've tried adding your example and still no luck :( am I entering the php correctly in the welcome message?
Welcome <?php echo $uname; ?>

Comment: Try changing your query like `$result = mysql_query("SELECT uname, pass FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname'");`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a good part of the issue.

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
$uname = $_POST["uname"];
```

Your setting your session's `uname` to blank on every load of that page.  Put `$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;` at the end of the code when it's validated.

Comment: Still no luck :( I will add my profile.php code into the question so you can have a better look. Thanks

Comment: `$uname` is not global - you have to reset it manually on that page again.  The part that you say `echo $_SESSION['uname']` should be `$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];`

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to add a value to $uname first, then assign its value to $_SESSION element, so it's better be like this:

```
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
```

or even like this:

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
```

2) As already mentioned, At profile.php you should also have session_start();

3) Make a clean exit like this:

```
header("Location: ../../profile/profile.php");
exit();
```

My bet is that it should be working fine after.

Answer (score 1):

Some how, this is now working. From what I can figure out, the solution was to call in the $_SESSION variable, and then wrap that inside another variable. so

```
<?php
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
  ?>
```

Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: I included some added information in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20302859/1415724) at the bottom which will prove to be beneficial, concerning [berkes' comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302674/php-use-a-variable-from-a-different-file#comment30294101_20302674)

Answer (score 1):

`session_start();` needs to be inside all pages using sessions.

I tested the following:

```
<?php 
session_start(); // page_2.php
echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['uname'];
?>
```

In conjunction with my test page: `page_a.php`

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$uname = "FRED";
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname; 
?>

<a href="page_2.php">CLICK</a>
```

Echo'ed `Welcome FRED` on page 2.

I also noticed you have another instance of `session_start();` in your page `profile.php`, **remove it** because you will be starting a new session while overwriting your first.

```
<div class="username">
Welcome <?php session_start(); echo $uname; ?>
</div>
```

Therefore you should be using:

```
$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
```

in conjunction with:

```
<div class="username">
<?php echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['uname']; ?>
</div>
```

---

As `berkes` stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302674/php-use-a-variable-from-a-different-file#comment30294101_20302674) you have a security issue:

```
$uname = $_POST["uname"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
```

Change it to:

```
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
```

`MySQL_` functions are deprecated, therefore using `MySQLi_` with prepared statements is highly suggested or PDO.

Do read the following articles:

- **[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1415724)**
- **[On owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)**